# Erro durante requisição de upload para amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-aws

Ao tentar fazer o upload de uma imagem está dando problemas e gostaria de saber qual o problema e como resolver.

Amazon request:

```
public void amazon() {
        String fileName = photoFile.getName();
        long mTotalFileBytes;

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

        metadata.setContentLength(mTotalFileBytes = photoFile.length());
        metadata.setContentType("image/".concat(fileName));

        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:my-cognito-code",
                Regions.US_EAST_1
        );

        amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        amazonS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1));
        try {
            por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, new FileInputStream(photoFile), metadata);
            if (postImageAsyncTask == null) {
                postImageAsyncTask = new PostImageAsyncTask();
            }
            postImageAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        amazonUrl = amazonS3Client.getResourceUrl(bucket, fileName);
        Log.e(">>>>>URL", ">>>>>" + amazonUrl);


    }
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class PostImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, PutObjectResult> {

    public PostImageAsyncTask() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    protected PutObjectResult doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            return amazonS3Client.putObject(por);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (AmazonClientException f) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PutObjectResult result) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            if (result != null) {
                docsIDController.pictureFinishedSendingToS3(amazonUrl);
            } else {
                postImageAsyncTask.cancel(true);

                if (RECONECT_TIME_DELAY < MAX_TIME_DELAY) {
                    if ((snackbar == null || !snackbar.isShown())) {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Ocorreu um problema de conexão, aguardando dispositivo se reconectar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        snackbar.setAction("Cancelar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                finishedTakingDocIDPicture(null);
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            RECONECT_TIME_DELAY = RECONECT_TIME_DELAY * 2;
                            postImageAsyncTask.cancel(true);
                            postImageAsyncTask = new PostImageAsyncTask();
                            postImageAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        }
                    }, RECONECT_TIME_DELAY);
                }
            }
        } else {
            postImageAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
I/AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x5c15d378: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
                                                                 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x5c15d378: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
                                                                     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
                                                                     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:717)
                                                                     at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:41)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.write(UrlHttpClient.java:172)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:129)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4204)
                                                                     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1618)
                                                                     at com.foregon.forid.pictureManagement.boundary.DocsIDUI$PostImageAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocsIDUI.java:488)
                                                                     at com.foregon.forid.pictureManagement.boundary.DocsIDUI$PostImageAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocsIDUI.java:478)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleff, vou compartilhar com você uma classe utilitária que eu mesmo fiz para enviar imagens ao S3. Eu ainda continuo utilizando ela e funciona super bem:

```
public class AmazonS3Utils {
    private static final String MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "SUA_ACCESS_KEY_ID";
    private static final String MY_SECRET_KEY = "SUA_SECRET_KEY";
    private static final String TAG = AmazonS3Utils.class.getSimpleName();
    private static AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    // FIXME: pode retornar null
    public static PutObjectRequest createPutObjectRequest(@NonNull String bucketName, @NonNull String objectName,
                                                          @NonNull File file) {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectName, file);
        return putObjectRequest;
    }

    // Exceção UnknownHostException é disparada caso não haja conexão com a internet
    public static void putObject(@NonNull PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest) throws UnknownHostException {
        getS3Client().putObject(putObjectRequest);
    }

    public static String generateImageUrl(@NonNull String bucketName, @NonNull String objectName) {
        return getS3Client().getResourceUrl(bucketName, objectName);
    }

    private static AmazonS3Client getS3Client() {
        if (amazonS3Client == null) {
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
            // 60 segundos
            clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000); // milliseconds
            amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_SECRET_KEY),
                    clientConfiguration);
            return amazonS3Client;
        }
        return amazonS3Client;
    }
}
```

Uma coisa importante a ressaltar é que talvez por não setar nada de metadata como você faz aqui `metadata.setContentType("image/");`,na hora de recuperar não há metadados da imagem, como orientação, por exemplo. Isso não tem problema para o meu escopo, aí depende de você querer adaptar para o seu caso.

Comment: Funcionou, tinha apenas de colocar `ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000);` e alterar `PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, photoFile);`

Comment: Ótimo! Feliz por ajudar, abraço.